# popmenu signin form:

Tags: javascript

please tell me how we can create popup signin form in javascript example see. http://www.imageshack.com.  please go to this site and click on myimage option then new small window is open and it contain username and password how we can create this in javascript, from where i can get itz source code..

Comment: Oh please, read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints first.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it very easily with the likes of JQuery and modal dialog's.
or if you want non-jquery based solutions, use absolute-positioned div's on top of another div that takes the whole page and has the transparency set to 50% or something -- in order to prevent clicking on other items on the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use fancybox for that it is very flexible plugin http://fancybox.net/